# EOL in SVN repository setting it to CRLF

Tags: svn, migration, eol

I'm migrating a CVS repository to Subversion using the polorion tool. When I import the dump created using svnadmin load, automatically the .java and .txt files are set to CRLF EOL. But the XML and html ect stay as LF.

The requirement is to set all these files with EOL as CRLF. I did setup the C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config to enable auto props and set the *.xml = svn:eol-style=native or even *.xml = svn:eol-style=CRLF.

However when I try to import this does not help.

I read about the RDC (Repository dictated configuration) . All support materials and tutorials explain the propget. But how to I setup this property at the repository level.

I can set this property as a one time thing(only for the dump file import) and remove it later. So when users are actually using it I donot need to enforce this.

Kindly help.

Comment: If you're just trying to "get away" from CVS and into something *more modern*, I'd directly go for git. I personally find it much better and easier to use, it has a cvs plugin that allows direct and automatic import etc.

Comment: The decision to move to SVN is a corporate level one and cant make a change there. Hence I have to stick with moving to svn

Comment: you can do that, by using git locally, and pushing to SVN. That has quite some advantages -- for example, you can locally have as many branches as you need to test new features, and merge them back into your SVN branch, before pushing to SVN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Marcus. After good of painstaking search I have found the solution. The svi importer till from polotion has a config.autoprops folder. This has the option to set the eol style in it. Setting this and creating svn dumps resolved the issue

Ps: answered this for my own future reference

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the detour over git, because I'm used to that (in fact, I'd just stick with git -- I personally find it **vastly** superior to SVN):

- install git-svn and git-cvs
- use git-cvs to import your CVS history
- use `sed`, converting all the files, and `git commit` that.
- use git-svn to push that to your SVN repo

**EDIT**: I forgot that you're using a strang operating system for development, where it's not easy to install standard tools. According to what I can *guess* based on the source code, [msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/) should contain git-svn capabilities. I'm not so sure about [git-cvsimport](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsimport), though. It might be easiest to just use any linux (maybe just use a live DVD) that has git installed, and git-cvsimport there, so you have the CVS history in a git repository, which you can then just clone/use under windows.

You should really read the [git/CVS migration guide](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcvs-migration)  (don't worry, not really long) -- it explains what you were missing when you used CVS.

Also, you said that moving to SVN was a corporate decision. I might criticize your corporation for that, but it would be to no avail. Instead, I might point out that you can stay totally corporate-rules compliant by using git locally to track your own branches, and only push to the corporate SVN repo when stuff is "shareable". In git, it's very very common to just start a branch in *your local repository* which you develop your new feature, or fix a certain bug etc, then verify everything works well, and then merge it back to *your* main development branch, before pushing that to the remote repository. Git does everything for you, normally. So even if a colleague of you changed the main dev branch while you were working on your feature branch, you'd still be able to easily merge your changes back into that -- SVN is, honestly, so much worse at that, that the additional work you get by preparing your git history to be SVN-publishable, is easily offset.

I've seen people "prefer" SVN over git, because they claimed that git was "too complex". Really, it's not. Also, people that decide that employes have to use SVN in 2015 deserve to solve the conflicts SVN causes when two people work on different features on the same branch.

Comment: Can you share a download link if possible. Google results are not precise.

Comment: why the downvote, people? that's a pretty interesting topic, so I'd actually love to see some comments.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Since the issue has been solved I've not tried it with GIT. however